# How to simulate sharing geolocation with Capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, testing, geolocation, capybara

My scenario calls for user giving permission for the app to user his location. This dialog looks different in every browser. How do I go about testing it with Capybara?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would mock/stub it if I needed it for the test suite flow and didn't want to call the API.
Unfortunately, with all goodnes of the automatic testing there are still a few % that need to be done manually. At least that I what I learned from my experience.

Answer (score 2):

I've successfully used this in a [Cucumber](http://cukes.info/) step definition:

```
page.execute_script "navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition = function(success) { success({coords: {latitude: 50.455755, longitude: 30.511565}}); }"
```

Comment: I like this solution as it allows one to mock out the expected result, thank you sir!

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing with Chrome, then this might be helpfull:

[How do I enable geolocation support in chromedriver for Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8411816/how-do-i-enable-geolocation-support-in-chromedriver-for-selenium/8745369#8745369)

Answer (score 0):

So, I liked the `page.execute_script` version above... however I discovered this didn't work with turbolinks.

After much Googling I came up with this as an alternative:

```
page
  .driver
  .browser
  .execute_cdp(
    'Page.setGeolocationOverride',
    accuracy: 100,
    latitude: latitude.to_f,
    longitude: longitude.to_f
  )
```

I'm not a big fan of this solution since it's accessing part of their "private api" which of course they recommend against... but it works for now.

**UPDATE**: At present this works for the selenium_chrome driver, but not selenium_chrome_headless... back to the drawing board.