# Webdriverio/chimpjs - Launch Google Chrome with Gelocation permitted

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-io, chimp.js

I am writing a web application that depends heavily on geolocation. I am using chimpjs (combination of cucumber, webdriverio, chai) to do my BDD. I would like to launch google chrome with geolocation allowed. I think I must do this because I can find no way to click the Allow button in chrome to allow geolocation.

I have a chimp.js config file in my cucumber directory. Here are its contents:

```
module.exports = {
  webdriverio: {
    desiredCapabilities: {
      chromeOptions: {
        deviceName: 'Google Nexus 5'
      }
    }
  },
  browser: 'chrome',
  watch: false,
  path: './features',
  chai: true,
  screenshotsPath: '.screenshots'
};
```

I know that:

- chrome uses profile information that may be provided around runtime
- there is an option 'geolocation' which must be set to 1
- some other relevant nesting are 'prefs' and 'default_content_setting_values', which I learned about from digging through my chrome preferences

What I cannot figure out is which among these need to be passed to chromeOptions, and what needs to be nested where.

I am sure I cannot be the only person who ever needed to launch chrome with webdriver and have geolocation enabled.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply configure this in `chromeOptions` with `profile.default_content_setting_values.geolocation`.

```
chromeOptions: {
  deviceName: 'Google Nexus 5'
  prefs: {
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.geolocation": 1,
  }
},
```

Comment: This one fixed it for me. Although I used it like this:   chromeOptions: 

{
            prefs: {
                'credentials_enable_service': false,
                'profile': {
                    'password_manager_enabled': false,
                    'default_content_setting_values': {
                        'geolocation': 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }

Answer (score 0):

This question is a duplicate of this one: [How do I enable geolocation support in chromedriver for Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8411816/how-do-i-enable-geolocation-support-in-chromedriver-for-selenium)

I've translated the answer to WebdriverIO syntax:

```
browser.execute(function() {
  window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition = function(success) {
    var position = { coords : { latitude: "40.748440", longitude: "-73.984559" } }; 
    success(position);
  }
});
```