# Python Selenium Change Geolocation

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, geolocation, google-geolocation

I am trying to trick the Python chromedriver to make it believe that it is running in a different city.

It appears someone has found an answer for this in [JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8411816/how-do-i-enable-geolocation-support-in-chromedriver?noredirect=1&lq=1), but I was wondering if it is possible to adapt it for Python using Selenium:

```
chromeDriver.executeScript("window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition = 
    function(success){
         var position = {"coords" : {
                                       "latitude": "30.9843", 
                                       "longitude": "91.9623"
                                     }
                         }; 
         success(position);}");
```

I tried all the suggested answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53772711/how-to-change-geolocation-of-chrome-selenium-driver-in-python), but none of them worked in Python.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/support_packages/chrome_devtools/

Comment: Incredible, thank you!