# How can I handle Geo Location popup in Safari using selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, safari

I am facing an issue with an auto prompt for geolocation on safari using selenium. I am not sure if I can do a selenium-click to disappear the prompt. does anyone know how can I disappear the prompt?

I tried several java code, I read some pages but look this issue was never result.

Comment: Can you provide a link to that prompt? Might be useful to see what is going on

Comment: Can you try the solution in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8411816/how-do-i-enable-geolocation-support-in-chromedriver.
Basically you can set your location after you start the driver and it should not prompt you with the pop-up

Comment: that could work on safari, let me check.
Thanks!

Comment: Oh forgot.. to mention that I just tried it on safari, not with your site but with another one and it worked

Comment: should be something like this:
String script = "window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition = function(success){ var position = {'coords' : {'latitude': '555','longitude': '999'}};success(position);}";
   chromeDriver.executeScript(script);

Comment: @NicLaforge did not work I changed "  to ' or \' but not result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to set up on the preference on safari never ask the location only on that way the pop up on safari never appear.

Comment: https://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/how-to-turn-off-safari-website-notifications/